# NP-Complete problems to Partition Problem reductions

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming, complexity-theory, reduction, np-complete

According to Wikipedia, **[Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (PP) is NP-Complete (NPC)** problem with existing **pseudo-polynomial time dynamic programming (DP) solution**. If a problem is NPC any NP problem can be reduced to instance of such problem in polynomial-time, i.e. Traveling salesman problem (TSP) instance to PP instance. Now there is no algorithm, DP or otherwise, for TSP to have better bound than `O(2^n)`.

**Now, why is that if I can take TSP instance, create PP instance out of it, solve PP instance in pseudo-polynomial time and reduce it back?** *The reductions only costing me something polynomial.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question here is “pseudopolynomial *in what quantity?*” For the knapsack problem, the pseudopolynomial-time algorithm runs in time O(nW), where W is the maximum weight of any of the items. If you actually try running through the details of reducing TSP (or most other NP-complete problems) to knapsack using the “standard” reductions known today, you’ll find that the weights on the items are enormous and typically exponential in the size of the inputs to those problems. For example, the typical reduction from set packing to knapsack works by building items whose weights are on the order of 2<sup>n</sup>, where n is the number of distinct items across all sets. That makes the runtime of first using this reduction and then applying knapsack O(n · 2<sup>n</sup>), which isn’t pseudopolynomial time.

Comment: I understand, thank you! If polynomial algorithm instead of pseudo-polynomial one existed for PP/Knapsack, this wouldn't be the problem since 'in what quantity' would be irrelevant then, right?

Comment: Yep, since a polynomial-time reduction from one problem to another would produce an input whose size is polynomial, and the solver for knapsack would then run in time polynomial in that input size.